# Proving that $y=x$ is an asymptote.

Tags: graphing-functions

I'm currently investigating the curve implicitly defined by $x^2-y^2= \ln (xy)$. Now I can see that by considering the region $xy>1$ and $xy<1$, we can determine where the curve is above or below the line $y=x$.

However, I do not feel that this is not enough to prove that the line $y=x$ is an asymptote in itself, just whether it approaches it from above or below.

For an implicitly defined curve like this, what kind of approach would I take to show that $y=x$ is an asymptote?

Comment: Have you seen this wiki page? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptote#Oblique_asymptotes

Comment: Yes I have. My issue is with the fact that there are two variables here, so I cannot simply take the limit as $x\rightarrow \infty$ and assume $y$ to be constant.

Comment: In fact $y\to\infty$ as $x\to\infty$. Did you already know that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could separate the variables:

$$x^2 - \ln x = y^2 + \ln y.$$

It's easy then to show that $y\to\infty$ as $x\to\infty$.

Take the ratio of the two sides:
$$\frac{y^2 + \ln y}{x^2 - \ln x} = 1.$$

For large positive $x$, you have large positive $y$ and $y^2/x^2 \approx 1$, 
so $y/x \approx 1$.

You can even write
\begin{align}
\frac{y^2}{x^2}
& = \left( \frac{y^2}{y^2 + \ln y} \right) \left( \frac{x^2 - \ln x}{x^2}\right)
 \frac{y^2 + \ln y}{x^2 - \ln x} \\
& = \left( \frac{y^2}{y^2 + \ln y} \right) \left( \frac{x^2 - \ln x}{x^2}\right)
\end{align}

Each of the quantities in parentheses goes to $1$ as $x\to\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

You can establish that $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{2x-\frac 1x}{2y+\frac 1y}\rightarrow 1$$ as $x,y\rightarrow +\infty$

Hence for large $x,y>0$, the graph is approximated by the line $y=x$

Comment: Do indeed $x,y\to+\infty$ imply that $x/y\to 1$?

Comment: @Berci...No it's because the gradient tends to 1

Comment: It seems like you are taking the limits simultaneously that as $x \rightarrow \infty$ then $y \rightarrow \infty$. However, how can we be sure that this is the case?

Comment: Why not $y=x+3$?